# Js variable to php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I’m trying to send a string of 13 ASCII characters from js to the PHP session using Ajax, but on receiving string is not the same as I send it, using `JSON.stringify` and `json_decode` does nothing.

```
    console.log(plik_T[click])
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: './Setyb.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {send: plik_T[click]},
        success: function (obj) {
           console.log(obj)
        }
        
    });
```

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST['send']);
?>
```

[image: console output]

I tried using `JSON.stringify` or changing meta UTF-8 to older versions none of this resolved my problem. Then I tried checking the type of variables which both were string, so that led me to nothing. what I'm trying to accomplish is to set my Session variable up on user click and use it in the next php page

Comment: "i tried using json.stringify" ... show how you used it your question.

Comment: data: {send: JSON.stringify(plik_T[click])},
and in php 
 var_dump(json_decode($_POST['send']));
output remains the same upon those changes

Comment: The strings you're getting back look the same to me as the ones you're sending. Please identify what you believe are the specific differences